# IOS - Drawing rounded corner square

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgcontext

I am trying to create a 200px square with rounded corners to use as an IOS toast style indication.

I have the following so far -

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.1].CGColor);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 10, 0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 95, 0);
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, 100, 0, 100, 5, 10);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 100, 95);
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, 100, 100, 95, 100, 10);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 5, 100);
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, 0, 100, 0, 95, 10);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 0, 5);
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, 0, 0, 5, 0, 10);
    CGContextFillPath(context);
}
```

I got this far by following a tutorial - it draws a perfect 100px with rounded corners square - but I need a 150px square!  I have changed every setting imaginable - with some bizzare results - but cant work out how the width height is defined!?  Can anyone advise?

Comment: 150 or 200? is not clear at me

Comment: If that is all that you are looking for then see Simon's answer. The framework provides you with everything you need. For more complex forms core graphics can be really helpful. When you draw your own drawings with core graphics then I'd suggest using variables (or constants to start with) such as with, height and conerRadius. First, it is easier to be programmed. But second and most it is more flexible. You would then just change the width and height from 100 to 150 and that's it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Update for Swift:

The below answer was correct that the time it was written for simple use cases. Things have changed a lot since then so heres an updated answer for swift.

You can create a UIView extension, to add methods to round all corners, or round specific corners. Adding `@IBInspectable` to the first property means it can be used in interface builder without requiring code

The second function is more complicated and can't be used as an `@IBInspectable` directly. It will need to be called inside the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` of the parent to ensure the mask doesn't cut off content as AutoLayout grows / shrinks the content.

```
extension UIView {

    @IBInspectable public var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
        set {
            layer.cornerRadius = newValue
        }
        get {
            return layer.cornerRadius
        }
    }

    public func roundCorners(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

Once added to your project you can simply do:

```
myView.cornerRadius = 4

or

myView.roundCorners(corners: [.topLeft, .topRight], radius: 4)
```

### Very old Objective-c answer:

If you import QuartzCore framework:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

and add it to your project, you can use the below:

```
UIView *temp = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
temp.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
```

Comment: This approach has a problem.. it requires offscreen rendering, if you are doing that (for instance) on a tableview cell elements it will reduce scrolling performance

Comment: this is to be added as a toast style update notification to a uitableviewcontroller - in this case am I better off implementing Templar's solution below?

Comment: @Andrea granted, but the user said they are trying to create an iOS toast style indication. Its going to be used as a pop up message on the screen. I thought it would be easier to give the user a simpler approach to understand

Comment: For you porpoise is totally fine, quick and not so dirty :-), very effective. I've put my comment just for sake of completeness ;-)

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin I agree with you!

Comment: @downVoter care to explain? 3 people upvoted and someone else said its a fine solution for this problem. It annoys me when people downvote in a situation like this. Clearly you have an issue with some of my code, I would love to know so that I can learn from it as much as the user. Please share

Comment: @Dancer Nah, It's much easier with cornerRadius in this case. Generally, you only use drawRect if you need special shapes, gradient, etc.

Comment: Quick solution, but won't work if you want to do more sophisticated drawing. For example, if you want to draw a shape, then a transparent rounded rect above it and again something on top of that rounded rect.

Comment: @DarkDust granted its not suited for more sophisticated applications. I agreed with Andrea's point on this above already. However in this case the user has told us what they are trying to achieve and based on the hardcoded sample in the question I felt the user needed an easier approach. If the user wants the easy way than this is fine, if the user wants the more advanced approach than your answer is correct. Multiple people have said the same, so its up to the user to decide as we don't have the information necessary to make that call on their behalf

Comment: cheers for all the help guys - to clarify - I need to use this view to make a toast view - which will contain a label and an icon image - it will be used to inform the user that their progress has been updated - a simple fade in/out process before returning them to another view.

Comment: ended up using a version of this method - so gave you the tick - cheers for everyones help though!

Answer (score 10):

If you must draw in `drawRect` and other stuff will be drawn in future, then just use bezierpath, otherwise see Simon's answer for simple rounded corners on a view

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
       [super drawRect:rect];
       [[UIColor blueColor] setFill];
       UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rect /*CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 150)*/ cornerRadius:10.0];
       [path fill];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

1. Convert numbers to variables/constants.
2. Change variables/constants values.
3. Profit!

Here's your code, modified to show what I mean (untested):

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    static CGFloat length = 100;
    static CGFloat rounding = 5;

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.1].CGColor);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, rounding * 2, 0);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, length - rounding, 0);
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, length, 0, length, rounding, rounding * 2);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, length, length - rounding);
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, length, length, length - rounding, length, rounding * 2);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, rounding, length);
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, 0, length, 0, length - rounding, rounding * 2);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 0, rounding);
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(context, 0, 0, rounding, 0, rounding * 2);
    CGContextFillPath(context);
}
```

I also wonder about the 10s in your code. As far as I can see they should be 5s instead. Anyways, the easier solution is to use a `UIBezierPath` as others have demonstrated (the layer solution does work, but it obviously won't work if you for example want to draw something below the rounded rect and something above it).

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use a bezier path?

```
CGFloat radius =  4;
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0,0,200,200);
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rect cornerRadius:radius];
[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.1] setFill];
[path fill];
```